# C'est de là qu'il faut nous relever et non de l'espace et de la durée, que nous ne saurions remplir

Tags: sens

<sub>[Source:](http://degaulle.lyc.ac-amiens.fr/matieres/philosophie/guyon/corriges/pascalrosopensant.htm) Blaise Pascal, *Pensées*,
fragment 347 de l'édition de Brunschvicg.

PS: Je suis tombé sur cet extrait au fond de la p. 110 de  *[Thought: A Very Short Introduction](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Thought-Short-Introduction-Tim-Bayne/dp/0199601720)* (2013) par Tim Bayne.</sub>

> Toute notre dignité consiste donc en la pensée. C'est de **[1.]** là **[Fin de 1]** qu'il faut nous relever et     **[2.]** non de l'espace et de la durée **[Fin de 2]**,
>   que nous ne saurions remplir. Travaillons donc à bien penser: voilà le principe de la morale."

3. Quel est l'antecédent de 1 ? Notre dignité ou la pensée ?
4. Je ne comprends pas 2 que (je conjecture) doit être interpreté au sens figuré. Car il est impossible pour les êtres humains de remplir l'espace (car le corps d'un adulte a une hauteur moyenne de 178 cm et une largeur moyenne de 30 c) et la durée (car nous sommes mortels), n'était-il pas absurde et superflu que Pascal ait même mentionné savoir les remplir?

Answer (score 1):

Les essais philosophiques comme celui-là demandent souvent un effort de réflexion, même pour un francophone. Je te donne mon interprétation, elle n'est pas forcément parfaite.

L'antécédent de [1.] est la pensée. C'est le sujet de la réflexion. Dire "*Notre dignité consiste en...*" veut dire que la pensée est quelque chose de noble.

Pascal oppose la pensée à ce que je pense être le "monde physique" quand il parle "*d'espace et de durée*" (on dirait l'espace et le temps aujourd'hui).

Il vaut mieux faire évoluer, progresser sa pensée que ce qu'on a dans le monde physique. Quelque chose comme ça. Je l'ai pas très bien dit mais je pense que l'idée est là.

(J'ai plus expliqué le sens philosophique que la grammaire, mais comme l'a dit jlliagre, ici "savoir" a le sens de "pouvoir" : jamais l'homme le pourra *remplir* l'espace et le temps (le sens de "remplir" est un peu flou et débatable ici.))

Answer (score 0):

1. La pensée: Il faut nous élever par la pensée.
2. Savoir est utilisé ici avec le sens de pouvoir. Affirmer une vérité n'est forcément absurde. Pascal souligne ici que la prétention de l'homme (« fini ») à occuper tout l'espace et le temps (« infinis ») est vaine.